# Sort negative decimal values

Tags: bash, sorting, decimal

Dealing with the processing of the log in the following format:

```
# the system name: dG
MD_cluster10_1_300K: -34.48
MD_cluster11_1_300K: -40.31
MD_cluster1_1_300K: -40.23
MD_cluster2_1_300K: -37.86
MD_cluster3_1_300K: -25.65
MD_cluster5_1_300K: -11.91
MD_cluster6_1_300K: -0.50
MD_cluster8_1_300K: -16.62
MD_cluster9_1_300K: -15.26
```

I need (ignoring the first line) to sort the data according to the values in the second column from most negative to positive, and save it as a new log.

Would the sort utility work for such case?

```
sort -n ./file_unsorted > file_sorted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk solution:

```
$ awk '/^#/{next};{a[$2]=$1}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; for (i in a)print a[i],i}' file
MD_cluster11_1_300K: -40.31
MD_cluster1_1_300K: -40.23
MD_cluster2_1_300K: -37.86
MD_cluster10_1_300K: -34.48
MD_cluster3_1_300K: -25.65
MD_cluster8_1_300K: -16.62
MD_cluster9_1_300K: -15.26
MD_cluster5_1_300K: -11.91
MD_cluster6_1_300K: -0.50
```

---

To see the above script formatted legibly, using GNU awk to pretty-print it:

```
$ awk -o- '/^#/{next};{a[$2]=$1}END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; for (i in a)print a[i],i}' file
/^#/ {
        next
}

{
        a[$2] = $1
}

END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        for (i in a) {
                print a[i], i
        }
}
```

Comment: Ciao Ivan ! may you please revrite your awk function in a general (not a one line) view in order that I could understand it better ? spasibo !

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for `sorted_in`.

Comment: @JamesStarlight since the script requires GNU awk and you accepted it so you must have GNU awk, you could pretty-print it by running `awk -o- '...'` to get legibly formatted output. I just added that output so others can see it too.

Comment: `/^#/{next};{a[$2]=$1}` = `!/^#/{a[$2]=$1}`

Answer (score 4):

**Command:**

```
grep -v '#' file_unsorted | sort -t ':' -k 2,2n > file_sorted
```

**file_unsorted:**

```
MD_cluster10_1_300K: -34.48
MD_cluster11_1_300K: -40.31
MD_cluster1_1_300K: -40.23
MD_cluster2_1_300K: -37.86
MD_cluster3_1_300K: -25.65
MD_cluster5_1_300K: -11.91
MD_cluster6_1_300K: -0.50
MD_cluster8_1_300K: -16.62
MD_cluster9_1_300K: -15.26
```

**Output (file_sorted):**

```
MD_cluster11_1_300K: -40.31
MD_cluster1_1_300K: -40.23
MD_cluster2_1_300K: -37.86
MD_cluster10_1_300K: -34.48
MD_cluster3_1_300K: -25.65
MD_cluster8_1_300K: -16.62
MD_cluster9_1_300K: -15.26
MD_cluster5_1_300K: -11.91
MD_cluster6_1_300K: -0.50
```

Comment: @Paolo updated with text output instead of image..

Comment: You could also consider having grep match a leading `#`: `^#`

Comment: `,2n` causes that reverse functionality do not work. `-n` is needed to properly handle leading zeros.  `sort -n -t ':' -k 2`

Comment: Since there's always a space before the number, you don't need `-t ':'` as sort uses spaces as the field separator by default.

Answer (score 3):

check this out too :

with sed

```
sed '1d' log.txt | sort -k2 -n
```

with tail

```
tail -n +2 log.txt | sort -k2 -n
```

with awk

```
awk 'NR>1{print | "sort -k2 -n"}' log.txt
```

output

```
MD_cluster11_1_300K: -40.31
MD_cluster1_1_300K: -40.23
MD_cluster2_1_300K: -37.86
MD_cluster10_1_300K: -34.48
MD_cluster3_1_300K: -25.65
MD_cluster8_1_300K: -16.62
MD_cluster9_1_300K: -15.26
MD_cluster5_1_300K: -11.91
MD_cluster6_1_300K: -0.50
```